# How to print number 1 to 10(in that sequence only)using loops(java) if int i = 10

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Output must be
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

I have tried
While loop but it prints from 10 to 1

Comment: Show your attempts.

Comment: in your while loop, just swap the number 10 and 1 and replace `i--` with `i++`

Comment: `while (i++ < 20) System.out.println(i - 9);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you must use `i` with an initial value of `10`.

```
for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(11-i);
}

// or using a while loop
int i = 10;
while(i > 0) {
    System.out.println(11-i--);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you can do this in one line.

`IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(number -> System.out.println(number));`